# How to convert this RDBMS schema to a MongoDB "schema" (and how to query against it)

Tags: php, python, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I am learning how to use MongoDB. It is taking me a while change my mindset from RDBMS/SQL to NoSQL.

Using the following tables and queries as an example, I am hoping that someone can explain how I may implement this trivial RDBMS schema using mongrel, and how I can implement the queries using mongodb.

```
CREATE TABLE tag_category (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(32) );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_tag_cat ON tag_category(name);

INSERT INTO tag_category(1, 'books');
INSERT INTO tag_category(3, 'music');
INSERT INTO tag_category(4, 'food');


CREATE TABLE tag (id INT NOT NULL, 
                  categ_id INT REFERENCES tag_category(id),
                  tagval   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
                 );

INSERT INTO tag (1,1,'romance');
INSERT INTO tag (2,1,'scifi');
INSERT INTO tag (3,1,'thriller');
INSERT INTO tag (4,2,'rap');
INSERT INTO tag (5,2,'country');
INSERT INTO tag (6,2,'jazz');
INSERT INTO tag (7,2,'classical');
INSERT INTO tag (8,3,'Chinese');
INSERT INTO tag (9,3,'Italian');
INSERT INTO tag (10,3,'French');
INSERT INTO tag (11,3,'South African');


CREATE TABLE item (id INT,
                  entry_date DATE NOT NULL, 
                  name VARCHAR(32) );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_item ON item(name);

INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(1, '2011-01-01', 'A love supreme');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(2, '2011-01-01', 'A kind of blue');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(3, '2011-02-01', 'Believe the hype');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(4, '2011-01-01', 'Raising Hell');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(5, '2011-01-01', 'The Chronic');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(6, '2011-02-01', 'Blue Danube');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(7, '2011-01-01', 'Schubert Sonata in B flat');
INSERT INTO item (id, entry_date, name) VALUES(8, '2011-01-01', 'Also Sprach Zarathrustra' );
-- ...

CREATE TABLE item_tag (id INT, 
                       item_id INT REFERENCES tag(id),
                       name VARCHAR(32) );

-- INSERT INTO item_tag (id, item_id, name) VALUES () ....
```

**QUERIES**

For brevity sake, I will describe a single query, which (hopefully) encompasses most of the use case scenarios I expect to encounter. The query below is trivial to implement using SQL - with mongrel, I'm not too sure how to do it:

- FETCH all items tagged as EITHER RAP OR Classical (in music category) that have an entry date greater than '2011-01-01'

To recap my question(s):

1. How would I 'port' the schema above so it can be implemented in mongodb
2. How would I request items as described in the query above, using the mongodb API?

I am familiar with both Python and PHP - so a solution using either PHP or Python APIs would be great (although I am biased in favour of Python).

Comment: do you have an idea how you would expect to handle this data structure in Python?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I am not sure I understand your question. Could you elaborate some more?.

Comment: sometimes if you already know how you will represent the data in your language of choice, it will naturally suggest modeling it a particular way in document DB.  So if in Python each item is a dictionary and tags are a list value of item['tags'] then that maps directly into JSON document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about document schema is that you don't have to translate to it from relational - you can consider it all on its own.  Consider the queries you will be making of the collection and then consider how you will work with the data in your language of choice.

I would consider something like a single collection where each document represents an item.  Each item can have a name, id, date of entry, and possibly a category as well as an array of tags.  I might also consider putting the category into array of tags just like it was another tag.  It depends on the queries and how different the items I will be storing will be (food and music probably calls for a separate category field).

If you keep category in its own field your documents may look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "entry_date" : ISODate("2011-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
    "title" : "A love supreme",
    "category" : "music",
    "tags" : [
        "jazz",
        "American"
    ]
}
```

If you use it as a tag, it would be like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "entry_date" : ISODate("2011-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
    "title" : "A love supreme",
    "tags" : [
        "music",
        "American",
        "jazz"
    ]
}
```

Now to query you would just do a `find` combining the conditions you wanted.  In case one it would be:

```
db.items.find({entry_date:{$gt:new Date(2011,0,1)},
                tags:{$in:["rap","classical"]}})
```

Technically you could add `category:"music"` if you might have these tags on movies or something else.

In second case it could be:

```
db.items.find({entry_date:{$gt:new Date(2011,0,1)}, 
               tags:"music",tags:{$in:["rap","classical"]}})
```

Since you can have [multi-key indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) on the tags array and MongoDB supports [compound indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys) (if you will routinely query by tags and entry_date), this would be a very efficient query.

Comment: Asya: Can you recommend a link (or book) that has a basic tutorial on building a simple app (e.g. blog), with mongodb as backend (either PHP or Python will do).